# C++ std::vector as Parameter for std::function

Tags: c++, function, vector

I am attempting to make callbacks in C++. The parameter for the callbacks are a vector that is passed by reference. The problem is that when I call the function, the vector is always empty. To demonstrate this, see the program below.

```
struct TestStruct {
    int x;
    int y;
};

void TestFunction( const std::vector<TestStruct> &vect ) {
    for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < vect.size(); i++ ) {
        printf( "%i, %i\n", vect[ i ].x, vect[ i ].y );
    }
}

int main() {
    std::map<std::string, std::function<void( const std::vector<TestStruct>& )>> map;

    std::vector<TestStruct> vect;
    map[ "test1" ] = std::bind( &TestFunction, vect );
    map[ "test2" ] = std::bind( &TestFunction, vect );

    std::vector<TestStruct> params;
    TestStruct t;
    t.x = 1;
    t.y = 2;
    params.emplace_back( t );

    map[ "test1" ]( params );
}
```

This is the closest example to what I am doing that I can give. I have saved the callbacks in a map. I then add the functions to the map. Then I make a generic TestStruct and put it in my params. Lastly I call the function and it should print out "1, 2" but instead nothing prints.

When I debug this it says the parameters are empty. This leads me to believe that I am doing something wrong or that this is not possible.

So what is going wrong here? Any help or tips are greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You want to bind with a `std::placeholders::_1`, not `vect`, i.e. `std::bind( &TestFunction, std::placeholders::_1);`, or actually, `map[ "test1" ] = &TestFunction;` should suffice (without `bind`)

Comment: @Piotr beat me to it.  http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/functional/bind/ see the example there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you write:

```
map[ "test1" ] = std::bind( &TestFunction, vect );
```

That gives you a nullary function that, when called, gives you the result of `TestFunction(vect)`. You are *bind*ing `vect` to the first parameter of `TestFunction`. So when you call it, you're printing the results of what's in `vect` (which is empty) instead of what's in `params` (which is not).

That isn't what you want at all - you want the actual function `TestFunction`:

```
map[ "test1" ] = TestFunction;
```

---

You would think this wouldn't compile. After all, you want a function that takes an argument, but you gave it a function that takes no arguments. But `bind()` simply ignores all arguments that it doesn't use.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to `bind` `TestFunction` with an empty `vector`. You can add it to the map directly.

```
map[ "test1" ] = TestFunction;
map[ "test2" ] = TestFunction;
```